# How to use APEX$ROW_SELECTOR with Dynamic Actions within an Interactive Grid

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Environment: Oracle APEX 5.1.2 / Oracle 12c

I'm currently using an Interactive Grid (IG) with the APEX$ROW_SELECTOR set to single record selection (i.e. radio group). What I am attempting to do, is use a Dynamic Action "Click" event off this APEX$ROW_SELECTOR, but unfortunately it's not firing when I click on the radio group selector.

I have the following questions based on the above:

1. How to add a Dynamic Action on row selection (APEX$ROW_SELECTOR) to fire when clicked?
2. When clicked, how to set a column value in session state to be used within a classic report?

Assuming the above is NOT possible with a Dynamic Action as part of an IG, how else can I perform something similar when a user selects a row with my IG?

Comment: You're mentioning radio group. But so far all examples I've seen with APEX$ROW_SELECTOR are based on tabular row check boxes, which returns X or NULL. Does the radio group trigger it?

Comment: I guess what I am trying to achieve here is the ability to capture a click event on each of the IG rows via a dynamic action as I then want to set session state and then pass this value into a classic report call.

Comment: I cannot verify if this works, but looks like this is a way to retrieve the data from  the clicked row: http://thejavaessentials.blogspot.com/2017/03/getting-selected-rows-in-oracle-apex.html

Comment: Also perhaps old fashion, but isn't using ROWID an option with Link Column? You could fetch the ROWID of the row of the IG, fetch it into a session, and process it further on the next page. This is a pretty standard implementation for interactive reports.

Comment: Requests for links and other external resources are off-topic here. From the official close reasons: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam_.

Answer (score 2):

You can search the class in the dom

.u-selector

[image]

Create a dynamic action using this class

[image]

[image]

And the result is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the below steps:

- You need to set a static class to the clickable column.
- Create a new dynamic action of type "click"
- The selection type would be JQuery Selector.
- in the Selector field you need to fill the static class you mentioned in the column attributes.
- You need to put the html id of the column as the id of the row and capture the value of it as follow in javascript:

this.triggeringElement.id -- it will capture the clicked item.

-Once you catch the value, you can set it to Page item and do whatever needed.